# See all open windows on windows when mouse is in top corner

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, mouse

This functionality exists on Ubuntu and the result is this [image]

It's triggered my moving the mouse to the top left of the screen, is there something similar in windows? 3rd party programs are fine, its one of my favourite features of ubuntu and I find myself trying to do it anytime I'm using my windows machine.

To be clear what I'm after is moving the mouse and showing open windows, not the ability to see all open windows.

Comment: There is a script that I have that would work for Windows 10. Would this help?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: update to Win10, press Win+TAB and you have this view in Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality I was looking for is available in [Switcher for windows](http://insentient.net/)